# Python Argparse usage instructions

Tags: python, argparse

I'am trying to write a function which can parse 1 or 2 ip addresses & a searchterm.

```
For example: ./system.py 172.16.19.152,172.16.19.153 model\ name
Output:
Search term: model name
Server: 172.16.19.152
Results:
Processor 0:
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Server: 172.16.19.153
Results:
Processor 0:
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

How can i get this usage instructions with argparse:

```
 usage:./system.py {IP}[,{IP}] {SEARCH\ TERM}
```

Comment: You can use argparse to parse a list of string separated by commas, then scan the list to get either one or two IPs. The search term is basic argparse.

Comment: Optionally you can also you `nargs` to limit the number of IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('ips',metavar='IP',nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('search_term',metavar='SEARCH\\ TERM',nargs=1)
```

The `metavar` keyword will be used in the usage text for your program. The double backslash is used for escaping the single backslash character for your `SEARCH\ TERM` argument. By calling `parser.parse_args()` the returning dictionary will contain your arguments parsed which can be reached like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args.ips
args.search_term
```

The `nargs` keyword will tell the number of this kind of argument to be passed to your program.

`+` means at least one, `1` means exactly one argument to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

To resume, you can use argparse as below.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--IP', nargs=2)
parser.add_argument('--TERM', nargs=1)
```